# Spring core helper to wait for all concurrent tasks

Tags: spring, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

There is a collection of tasks given as [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) or [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) objects. It is necessary to execute these tasks concurrently with one timeout for all tasks, thus if timeout is 3 seconds then in 3 seconds either all tasks should complete or `TimeoutException` should be registered.

In JDK the given operation is present as [`ExecutorService#invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>>, long, TimeUnit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29), but since Spring framework hides this interface behind `AsyncTaskExecutor` it is not possible to benefit from it. Copy-paste of the code is not an option.

What is the best way out? I would suggest that given functionality is implemented as a helper method in some utility class in Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find something useful in spring core. 
IMHO the best way is to use [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Pass it into Callable and call `countDown()` after work is done with `await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` in 'main' thread. Note that `await(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` returns boolean without throwing any `TimeoutException`.

Comment: Thanks for advise. It makes sense as a workaround, however needs each `Callable` implementation to be aware of the counter (decrease it after work is done).